# Does Docusign SDK compatible with java8

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, docusignapi

I'm trying to use docusign java launcher, but the documents says that it's compatible with java 11, can I used it with java 8 ?
or can I send Raw request instead ?

Answer (score 0):

This is our minimal supported version. It is possible you can get it working with an earlier version (I heard some folks said they were able to do it), but if you don't - we will ask you to upgrade.